# How to make an overridable function in API(ANDROID), with parameters and overridable by user

Tags: java, android, api, callback, overriding

I am developing an API in android which is to be used with beacons(BLE devices), the problem is that how should an overridable function be defined such that all the information(name, mac address,Rssi) about the beacons is passed in the function as an array (from the backend API side to the frontend - user code side) and the function is overridden by the user, as the user imports the API, to define actions to be taken on the passed array.

The code which is used for scanning the beacons is :

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

             @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
```

I searched online and found a way, that consists of making an interface and declaring an abstract function inside it and then it can be overridden by the user. 
The problem is that how should the details (as array) of the discovered beacons be sent to the user, and user should be able to get those details in the overridden function.

Comment: Is that overriden function called by your API? Is it some sort of callback-function? If so, then these information can be given through parameters (i.e. function arguments). Actually the snippet you quote is an example of exactly that.

Comment: The definition has to be set by the user, but the array has to be passed by the API in the function.

Comment: Yes, then do so. What's the problem?

Comment: The array which has to be sent to the function always returns null when called by the user

Comment: But if it is a callback then the user isn't supposed to call it! The API shall call it providing a non-null array. If the API provides null then you'll have to check the API code.

Comment: Also, if you polled the API for that info, what happens if there aren't any beacons found? Will this return null or an empty Collection/Array? I'd suggest 1. using a (immutable) Collection over an array. 2. returning an empty collection over null if nothing is found.